# Behaviour of photons in different materials

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, heat-conduction

Often when learning about heat transfer within metals and thermal conductors,the heat transfer is explained by saying how molecules vibrate in thier positions to conduct heat.

But if that's the case then how is heat observed externally as thermal radiations and how does the transfer actually take place for these radiation from one atom to another.If these radiation can travel in solids why doesn't light. ex. If I placed a bulb within a metal shell why can't I observe visible light outside the metal.